# Object resets when passed

Tags: c++

I have been practicing c++ lately, and came across this exercise where I am struggling a little with reference of objects.

> ClockUTC.h

```
#include "ClockUTC.h"

ClockUTC::ClockUTC()
{
    hour = 0;
    minute = 0;
}

ClockUTC::ClockUTC(int hour, int minute)
{
    this-> hour = hour;
    this-> minute = minute;
}

int ClockUTC::getHour()
{
    return hour;
}

int ClockUTC::getMinute()
{
    return minute;
}

void ClockUTC::setHour(int hour)
{
    this->hour = hour;
}

void ClockUTC::setMinute(int minute)
{
    this->minute = minute;
}
```

ClockUTC.cpp

```
#ifndef CLOCKUTC_H_INCLUDED
#define CLOCKUTC_H_INCLUDED


#include <iostream>


using namespace std;



class ClockUTC {

private:
int hour;
int minute;

public:
    ClockUTC();
    ClockUTC(int hour, int minute);
    int getHour();
    int getMinute();
    void setHour(int hour);
    void setMinute(int minute);
};


#endif // CLOCKUTC_H_INCLUDED
```

> ClockTZ.h

```
#ifndef CLOCKTZ_H_INCLUDED
#define CLOCKTZ_H_INCLUDED



#include <iostream>
#include "ClockUTC.h"


using namespace std;



class ClockTZ : public ClockUTC{

private:
ClockUTC clockUTC;
int offset;

public:
    ClockTZ(ClockUTC clockUTC, int offset);
    ClockUTC getClockUTC();
    int getOffset();
    void setClockUTC(ClockUTC clockUTC);
    void setOffset(int offset);
};




#endif // CLOCKTZ_H_INCLUDED
```

> ClockUTC.cpp

```
#include "ClockTZ.h"


 ClockTZ::ClockTZ(ClockUTC clockUTC, int offset)
{
    this->clockUTC = clockUTC;
    this->offset = offset;
    clockUTC.setHour(clockUTC.getHour() + offset);
}


ClockUTC ClockTZ::getClockUTC()
{
    return clockUTC;
}


int ClockTZ::getOffset()
{
    return offset;
}


void ClockTZ::setClockUTC(ClockUTC clockUTC)
{
    this->clockUTC = clockUTC;
}



void ClockTZ::setOffset(int offset)
{
    this->offset = offset;
}
```

And here the main file is:

```
/**
   Unit tests for 2nd EOOP assignment.

   ClockUTC - aggregate 2 integers (hour, minute)
   ClockTZ - view for ClockUTC, store reference to clockUTZ and offset

   Note that this is in a big part "code reading" exercise.
   Based on this file you should implement two classes mentioned above,
   with proper interface, and in right header file.
 */

    #include "ClockTZ.h"
    #include <iostream>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    int main() {
    
        ClockUTC greenwich(9,17);
        ClockTZ warsaw(greenwich, 2);
    
        if (warsaw.getHour() != 12){
            cout << "Error in getHour() 1" <<  endl;
        }
    
        return 0;
    }
```

I have coded the above files, and the only problem is after creating the ClockUTC class and passing it to the ClockTZ, ClockUTC resets and it is calling it's empty constructor and setting the hour to 0 instead of it's value + the offset as intended. I know it is because that the object is not having any reference and it is being destroyed as soon as passed or something, but don't seem to be able to fix it.

> Current output: 0

> Expected output: 12

I have tried fixing it by applying the & reference, but nothing seem to work. Can someone help me applying it properly?

Comment: 9+2 ==  11 why 12 in your test?

Comment: my bad, I changed the 10 to 9 and forgot to return it back. Was testing something :/

Comment: Do not use `using namespace std;` in your header files. Remember that every header file is just copy-pasted in place where you `#include` it. So your `using` directive will afftect every file where you include this header. One day this will bring a thousand of compile errors and all of them will seem meaningless

Comment: Please refrain from making edits that render answers incomprehensible.

Answer (score 1):

`ClockTZ` has two `ClockUTC` objects:  a *base class*, and a *member variable* named `clockUTC`.  The `ClockTZ` constructor will initialize the member variable by copying the value passed in, and will default initialize the base class.  When you later call `getHour`, the base class is called, returning the default value of `0`.

Comment: So how can I go about fixing this? Both the base class and the member variable are required in here.

Comment: @vepew26247 You should have only one or the other, not both.  From the problem description in the comment in the main file, it sounds like neither approach is what's being looked for here (since it mentions "reference to").

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm can you please show me how I can fix it to learn?

Comment: @vepew26247 I'm guessing you should have `ClockUTC &clockUTC;` as a class member (so the constructor will also have to take its `ClockUTC` parameter as a reference, then you'd want to use the member-initializer-list to initialize it.

Comment: I did this, but it says error: uninitialized reference member in 'class ClockUTC&' [-fpermissive]|